# SP2013 crawling not include subfolder and item below

Tags: crawling

In our SP2013 farm, we are using continuous crawling. The content source is setup to crawl entire web application. No rule is set.

In one of new added site collection, there is a default "Pages" library which store all the aspx web pages. Under "Pages" library there are several subfolders. Under the subfolders there are several aspx web pages, too.

All the aspx pages under "Pages" are crawled as expected. However, by some reason, even after full crawl, all the aspx pages under "Pages/subfolderXXX" are not being crawled. I checked against other site collections on this farm have do not have problem.

What can be went wrong?

Comment: In the "Pages" library settings I have clicked "Reindex doc library" button and still no change.

Comment: After checking the crawl log, I found all the pages under subfolder are deleted... "Deleted by the gatherer ( This item was deleted because the crawler did not encounter it during the last incremental crawl. )"